# regex: detect if character after an end of a sentence is in lowercase

Tags: php, regex

I want to detect if the first character after the end of a sentence is a lowercase.

For example:

```
Howdy world? lorem // match
Howdy world... lorem // match
Howdy world?   lorem // match
What is reality. howdy // match
Howdy you. Lorem // no match
Howdy you. 進撃の // no match
```

The end of a sentence is defined by these characters: `.!?`

What type of regex could I use to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to match these end of sentence punctuation marks if they are followed with whitespace and a lowercase letter?

Comment: Yes, although it can be more than one white space. Like the third example I have above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match these end of sentence punctuation marks if they are followed with whitespace and a lowercase letter, use

```
'~\w+[.?!]+\s+(?=\p{Ll})~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR5hB8/5)

*Explanation*:

- `\w+` - 1+ alphanumeric/underscore symbols
- `[.?!]+` - 1+ literal `.`, `?` or `!`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace symbols...
- `(?=\p{Ll})` - followed with 1+ whitespace characters followed with a lowercase letter (see [*Unicode character properties*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for `\p{Ll}` details and more Unicode category classes).

In PHP, use the `/u` modifier since you are working with Unicode strings.

Here is a [PHP code demo](https://ideone.com/VmAYpT):

```
$re = '~\w+[.?!]+\s+(?=\p{Ll})~u'; 
$arr = array("Howdy world? lorem", "Howdy world... lorem", "Howdy world?   lorem", "What is reality. howdy ",
    "Howdy you. Lorem ", "Howdy you. 進撃の "); 
print_r(preg_grep($re, $arr));
// => Array([0] => Howdy world? lorem    [1] => Howdy world... lorem
//[2] => Howdy world?   lorem    [3] => What is reality. howdy )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Only one remaining question. When it finds a match, is it possible to highlight the ending word of the sentence (including the ending punctuation). See this example: https://regex101.com/r/gR5hB8/2 -- the term **world?** and **world...** etc should be highlighted.

Comment: Maybe [`'~\w+[.?!](?=\s+\p{Ll})~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/gR5hB8/3). Or add a `\s*` after `\w+` if there can be whitespace between the word and the final punctuation.

Comment: YES! Exactly, is it possible to add the white space that follows the ending of the sentence as well, please see image for clarification: http://i.imgur.com/Zm6SPCE.jpg

Comment: Just put it into the consuming part of the pattern: [`'~\w+[.?!]+\s+(?=\p{Ll})~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/gR5hB8/5). Note the `+` after `[.?!]+`.

Comment: I'll bounty this with 50 points once eligible because it appears it's more complicated than what I estimated. Somehow, while this matches on regex101, it doesn't seem to work in my own function. I'm working on a split sentence function, please see: http://ideone.com/wz6CH7 -- you can find your regex there (see comments). It should not split the sentence if your regex is a match, but seems like it does it anyway.

Comment: See [the updated demo](http://ideone.com/7vbKEZ) where I moved the regex to the first position in the `$after_regexes` array. I do not think you need exactly that, but I guess that is something you need to check - the position of the regex inside the array. Also, recheck the meaning of `m` modifier: it redefines `^` and `$` meanings in PHP, while in Ruy that flag redefines `.` behavior (I remember that code was "translated" by ndn from Ruby into PHP).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the updated demo is still not splitting the sentences correctly...? (incorrect link?)

Comment: It is splitting the string into two strings. How should it work? I believe you need to update the question (although that is not a good thing, you know, to change topics like that)

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarification, this is what's desired: http://i.imgur.com/coXMZWr.png

Comment: That's a lot of regexes. This is actually quite a neat function!

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. I will mark this as correct as it solved the initial question that I asked! Btw, are you saying that I should strip all the "m" modifiers from the regexes?

Comment: @Henrik I will have a look at the Ruby code and perhaps provide a comment to the original ndn's answer. Just it is not that easy to find time for that at the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like so: `[.!?]\s*[a-z]` (example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/eQ6bG9/2)).

This will match any lower case letter of the **English alphabet** which is after a `.`, `!`, or `?` character and optionally white spaces.